# Why does not Unity cache components for me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, game-engine, game-development

I've created my own wrapper for GetComponent() so that I could use it wherever I wanted without perfomance concerns.

Why does not Unity do that in the first place? Could there be problems with such simple trick?

My code (intended to be used as a base class instead of MonoBehaviour):

```
public abstract class MonoBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Component> _components = new();

    public new T GetComponent<T>() where T : Component
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        
        if (!_components.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var component = gameObject.GetComponent<T>();
            
            if (component != null)
                _components.Add(type, component);
            else
                _components.Add(type, gameObject.AddComponent<T>());
        }
        
        return (T)_components[type];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Unity, so my question may be dumb - but what if you have more than one component of a certain type?

Comment: Haven't thought of that, thanks! But to be honest I've never seen two components of the same type on an gameobject, so I'd think that would be poor design to have them

Comment: Your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: Unity basically already does something similar on compilation time! It creates and stores a hashtable in the GameObject itself for which components are attached .. that's why `GetComponent` is already way faster in current versions than it was a couple of years ago ;) Also note that you do not always want to create a component in case it doesn't exist ... and with what you are doing ... how would you know it the component did exist already or was just created and might be missing some references and initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It adds to the memory overhead of your behaviour and also adds at least one heap allocation for each of its instances.
- It fails if components get removed and maybe re-added at runtime.
- Directly caching the component e.g. in Awake() into its own variable is still more performant.

Of course these points may be negligible in many of your use-cases, and you can surely use it where you see fit, but it is not a good idea in every situation, which is why it should not be put into the general implementation.